# Return entire Object With Largest Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, math

I have two arrays containing single objects I need to check which transaction contains the larger price property and then return the full array object. I am able to check which price is higher using the mathMax function but then I am only able to return the single price object. I am struggling to find a way to check the entire transaction object for which transaction has the larger price and then return the ENTIRE transaction object not just the price.

Thank You.

```
const compareTopTransaction = (transaction1, transaction2) => {
   const topValue = Math.max(
        transaction1.price,
        transaction2.price,
    ).toString();

    return topValue;
};
```

Goal here^ is to return either transaction1 object or transaction2 object after checking which has largest price

Comment: what is the expected return if the prices are equal?

Comment: `transaction1.price > transaction2.price ? transaction1 : transaction2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the transaction with the larger price by comparing on the `price` key

```js
const compareTransactions = (t1, t2) => t1.price > t2.price ? t1 : t2

console.log(
  compareTransactions({ price: 500 }, { price: 1000 })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the transactions by price, then return the first index of the array, provided that the array's order is unimportant. If it is important, you could do something like this.

```js
let currentTop = -1;
let topIndex = -1;
transactionsArray.forEach((transaction, index) => {
  if (currentTop < transaction.price) {
    currentTop = transaction.price;
    topIndex = index;
  }
});

const topTransaction = transactionsArray[topIndex];
```